# Append function in menu is greyed. What can I do to fix it?

Tags: blend-files, append

I'm trying to add an object from a previous project, but in the *File* menu bar the append option appears greyed out.

If I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, I can browse between the folder of my PC, but when I click on the file or press <kbd>Enter</kbd> that I need nothing happens.

[image: The menu bar of file]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was that **I was in Edit Mode** where append can't be used ,so you need to **switch to the Object Mode** and it's done

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/110628)

Comment: Sorry @Nate_Sycro27 , I wrote the answer in the wrong way, I hope in this way it's more clear what's the solution